# Forest plot columns with R Plotly Annotations

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, r-forestplot

**Typo in code has been fixed so that it should now be reproducible**

I am new to posting on StackOverflow so please let me know should my question or example not be clear enough and I will add more information as needed.

I am trying to develop a forest plot in `R` using `plotly`. For this, I need to be able to position the text along the y axis as if it were a formatted table (column content should be left-aligned for text, right-aligned for numbers, [see here for an example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/core/lw/2.0/html/tileshop_pmc/tileshop_pmc_inline.html?title=Figure%2021.%20Forest%20Plot%20of%20Odds%20Ratios%20for%20Mortality%20(KQ4b)%2C%20Comparing%20Alcohol%20Counseling%20Intervention%20and%20Control%20Groups%2C%20by%20Population.&p=BOOKS&id=534912_ch3f21.jpg)).
My initial solution was to have one, long, formatted string per y axis tick (using print formatting). This works, but only for monospaced font.

So now I am trying to use annotations instead of y axis labels. The difficulty lies in placing each annotation/column correctly outside the plotting area to created the desired formatting.
I first wanted to find the widest string in a column and to calculate the normalized coordinates accordingly, but I am not experienced in this so although I could get the annotations to show up as left-aligned columns, my conversions were wrong and the spaces between the columns were large. Here is what I used to try and figure out the coordinates. If you can point me towards other functions for this or know how I can work with these coordinates, this would definitely be my preferred solution. Note that the number of columns to be plotted to the left/right of the plot will be selected dynamically by the user, and so the plot's margins also need to be able to adjust. And I believe those have to be provided in pixels, so this brings along another conversion, from normalized coordinates to pixels...

```
  longestMpg = max(strwidth(mtcars$mpg, unit = 'in'))
  coord = grconvertX(longestMpg, from = 'inches', to = 'ndc') #normalized device coordinates
  # coord = grconvertX(longestNames, from = 'inches', to = 'npc') # normalized plot coordinates
  # coord = grconvertX(longestNames, from = 'inches', to = 'nfc') # normalized figure coordinates
```

So now I have moved on to placing each column/annotation into a separate plot  at `x = 0` and to trying to combine them into one subplot at the end (not a very elegant workaround...). The problem here is that the text shows up left-aligned for each plot separately (I am not trying to mix left-aligned and right-aligned text at this point), but as soon as I put both plots into one subplot, the text in the second plot is center-aligned. Here is a very simple example:

```
library(plotly)

# Plot only mtcar$disp
aPlot = plotly_empty(mtcars, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
  config(
    displayModeBar = FALSE
  )

for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  aPlot = aPlot %>% add_annotations(x = 0,
                                    y = i,
                                    text = mtcars$disp[i],
                                    xref = 'paper',
                                    yref = 'y',
                                    showarrow = F) %>%
    layout(yxaxis = list(showline = T), yaxis = list(showline = T))

}

# Plot only mtcar rownames
bPlot = plotly_empty(mtcars, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>%
  config(
    displayModeBar = FALSE
  )
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  bPlot = bPlot %>% add_annotations(x = 0,
                                    y = i,
                                    text = rownames(mtcars)[i],
                                    xref = 'paper',
                                    yref = 'y',
                                    showarrow = F) %>%
    layout(yxaxis = list(showline = T), yaxis = list(showline = T))

}

# Subplot
subplot(aPlot, bPlot, shareX = T, shareY = F)
```

Maybe there is an easier, more elegant way to achieve what I am looking for and I am happy to learn something new so please don't hesitate to share your ideas.
Grateful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately your question isn't reproducible. Please share the output of `dput(plotData)` or `dput(head(plotData))` with us. Regarding `column content should be left-aligned for text, right-aligned for numbers` your example shows all columns left aligned? Btw. are you aware of [plotly tables](https://plotly.com/r/table/)?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me @ismirsehregal. My bad - replace `plotData` with `mtcars` and it should work (plotData is the original data set that I cannot share here, so I used mtcars to try and illustrate).
The final goal is to be able to be flexible and mix and match alignment. At the moment I am just happy if I can figure out how to have everything left-aligned or right-aligned.

I did not know plotly tables. This looks like a very good solution, if I can figure out how to exactly align the table rows with the data so that the table looks as if it were the annotation for the plot.